# RecyclerView with two viewtypes dont save view state on scroll

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with two viewtypes, one is a header and another one is my products, now, when I select lets say 5 times one product, I stackup that quantity in the item view, but when I scroll down and up, the view is restored without saving the view state, I know that is because recyclerview recycle the view and then just recreates it on scroll when onBindViewHolder() is hit, but I need to retain this views state and not to change.

I dont have a checkbox in my selector that I could check if its selected or not, instead, I need to just keep the view as it is and not changing it on scroll

I have tried implementing `getItemId` and `setHasStableIds(true)` but there is not working in my adapter

```
 override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return super.getItemId(position)
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when {
            uiItems[position] is String -> {
                HEADER_VIEWTYPE
            }
            uiItems[position] is Product -> {
                PRODUCT_VIEWTYPE
            }
            else -> {
                -1
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I save the view state without changing the whole row when scrolling up and down in my recyclerview ?

Comment: just add variable in uiItems that hold the change and in function onBindViewHolder use that

Comment: Main idea behind RecyclerView and ListView with holder pattern is, we need not save the state. As View is about to appear on screen, the particular View based on View type via the ViewHolder will be inflated. This enables to have a proper View recycling. Please maintain the state in Adapter and reuse them with appropriate ViewHolder.

Comment: good to know your problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding one more element to my object that holds that quantity and then restores it in `onBindViewHolder()`